# Best way from Central Rotterdam to Europoort

Tags: transportation, ferries, netherlands, rotterdam

I'm going to a conference in Rotterdam (Maassilo, Maashaven Zuidzijde 1-2) next week (friday) and need to get to the Europoort for my ferry home straight afterwards.

I've booked a seat on the bus from the central train station, but it leaves before the conference finishes which means I'll have miss the end in order to get home.

A taxi would be about €90 which is a way too much for me, and I can't seem to find another route (bus, metro, etc).

So, does anyone have any advice on how I can stay for the end of my conference (17:00), and maybe a few drinks after, but still make my 19:30 (latest) checking?

---

**Update**: I've accepted Bart's answer as correct because there doesn't seem to be any cheap and fast route from Maashaven to Europoort. I had to leave the conference early to make it to the coach laid on by P&O. I'll update this question again if I go back and figure something better out.

Comment: Could you add in which part of Rotterdam the conference will be? And also what "the end of my conference" mean in terms of hours and minutes? This will help people to find a tailored answer for your question.

Comment: @Bart, yeah, I guess that would help :)

Comment: and what you mean by 'best' - cheapest/most-luxurious/certain time/something else?

Comment: I would say it's obvious that the OP is looking for a cheaper solution than the taxi which also enables him to stay until 17:00 at the conference. So best would be a solution where cost is less than €90 and certain time is 19:30 arrival at the port.

Comment: @BartArondson so would I, but we've seen several cases in the past where that hasn't happened, so it's always best to clarify potentially ambiguous text :)

Comment: @PeterCoulton What was your eventual solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best option would be if you could get a ride from someone at the conference, but as you mention `a few drinks after` I'm not sure if there will be someone willing to drive.

Other options to get from the [Maassilo](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Venue+Maassilo+B.V.,+Maashaven+Zuidzijde,+Rotterdam,+The+Netherlands&hl=en&sll=51.941514,4.161072&sspn=0.070267,0.181789&oq=maassilo&hq=Venue+Maassilo+B.V.,+Maashaven+Zuidzijde,+Rotterdam,+The+Netherlands&t=m&z=15) to the [Europoort P&O ferry terminal](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=P%26O+Ferries,+Luxemburgweg,+Europoort,+The+Netherlands&hl=en&ll=51.94617,4.134293&spn=0.070259,0.181789&sll=51.941514,4.161072&sspn=0.070267,0.181789&oq=p%26o&hq=P%26O+Ferries,&hnear=Luxemburgweg,+Botlek,+Europoort+Rotterdam,+Rotterdam,+Zuid-Holland,+The+Netherlands&t=m&z=13) are quite limited. The only regular public transport that goes directly where you want to go is the bus you mention.

Other public transport is possible, but will take you [3.5 hours](http://9292.nl/en/journeyadvice/rotterdam_bus-tramhalte-metromaashaven/europoort-rotterdam_luxemburgweg/arrival/2013-03-01T1844).