# Where can I go by boat from Amsterdam?

Tags: amsterdam

Where can I go by boat from Amsterdam ?
What are the closest destinations, in the North Sea and how long are the trips ?

Any link to a website about it is welcome. I need an introduction to the topic.

Comment: Do you have your own boat, or do you want to make a trip? What kind of destinations are you interested in?

Comment: This question is to broad, given that you can pretty much travel whole of the Netherlands and great part of neighboring countries by boat. Be more specific about the trip you're looking for.

Comment: What kind of boat do you have?

Comment: @Bernhard My boat. I'm actually planning to buy a boat next year but I dunno yet which one, how big, where I can go, etc. I really need some general information about itineraries and which boat I do need.

Comment: @vartec I see, I've seen you are from Amsterdam like me. Can you suggest me some website about boating outside Amsterdam? The ideal for me would be to have a boat to both use in the city canals and for longer trips.

Comment: @Gagravarr See comments above

Comment: @Patrick: sorry, I'm not from A'dam, I'm in A'dam. And I'm not into canal boating. Anyway, the Netherlands have 6000km of waterways. There are numerous books on the subject. For example: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0983284121 http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/184623185X http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0852889763

Comment: @Patrick Are you looking to take a sightseeing excursion (day trip) by boat from Amsterdam ?

Comment: You can even go to USA or China by boat

Comment: @Simon Yes, but also eventually go to Denmark or Norway  in the next years when I'll be more experienced... I need to know what kind of boat to get, and how much time/costs these kind of trips take...

Comment: @Dirty-flow Something easier for a beginner ?

Comment: @Patrick When you mean eventually go to Denmark & Norway when you have more experience - You mean to say: you want to know how to navigate a boat from Amsterdam so to eventually go by boat to Scandinavia ?

Comment: The question is far too broad. With a decent sized boat, anywhere that is accessible by boat is accessible from Amsterdam.

Comment: @DJClayworth Agreed, I don't really understand, especially with the comments regarding going to Denmark, Norway in the future

Comment: @DJClayworth What's the size of a "decent sized boat" ?

Comment: @Patrick Have you recently bought a boat ?

Comment: @Simon No, I would like to have an overview of which boat to buy, and trips I could have. I know the question is very broad, I'm sorry about that, but I need to get some information to start somehow

Comment: @Simon maybe we could have a chat ?

Comment: @Patrick Any boat that is capable of 'blue water' sailing - i.e. across oceans. Details of that kind of boat are probably off topic here. You should probably ask on The Great Outdoors, since boating questions are on-topic there.

Comment: @Patrick Oh I see, you should have stated that in your question, as it stands it sounds more like a day trip question

Answer (score 3):

There are no international ferries leaving from Amsterdam, but there are ferries going from [IJmuiden](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/IJmuiden) or [Hoek van Holland](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hoek_van_Holland).

IJmuiden is [27 km from Amsterdam](http://goo.gl/maps/CyhWB) and has ferry connections to [Newcastle](http://www.dfdsseaways.nl/).

Hoek van Holland is [85 km from Amsterdam](http://goo.gl/maps/Ey7Js) and has ferry connections to [Harwich](http://www.stenaline.co.uk/ferry/routes/harwich-holland/).  You can buy a [combined rail+ferry ticket](http://www.stenaline.co.uk/ferry/rail-and-sail/holland/) that will take you from Amsterdam to London.

Both IJmuiden and Hoek van Holland are well-connected by public transportation.

Comment: Well connected by public transportation? http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13900/best-way-from-central-rotterdam-to-europoort But, both companies have their own busses driving to the city centre.

Comment: I don't know whether this was really the kind of answer @Patrick was looking for.

Comment: @Bernhard The ferry I mentioned does not leave from the Europoort but from Hoek van Holland, and the ferry leaves virtually from the train station.  Stenaline actually sells [combined tickets](http://www.stenaline.co.uk/ferry/rail-and-sail/holland/).  I've just checked Google Maps and there does appear to be a ferry to the UK from the Europoort to Hull; this is not the ferry I was talking about and I am not familiar with this one.

Comment: @gerrit the OP wants to buy a boat and drive it himself, not to use ferries