# Other public transport from Rotterdam Central Station to Europort

Tags: public-transport, pets, rotterdam

"Other public transport is possible, but will take you 3.5 hours". Bart Arondson mentioned this possibility for getting from Rotterdam Central to the Europort on 24th February [as an answer to a previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13900/best-way-from-central-rotterdam-to-europoort/13903#13903). Does anybody know what other possibility he meant? We need to travel with a small dog in the pet carrier and P&O Shuttle bus doesn´t allow any pets. Normal taxi for two of us would be too expensive. Could you advice us please? We have plenty of time to get there, so we don´t mind if it takes a bit longer.

Comment: In my answer I [linked the 3.5 hours](http://9292.nl/en/journeyadvice/rotterdam_bus-tramhalte-metromaashaven/europoort-rotterdam_luxemburgweg/arrival/2013-03-01T1844) to the 9292.nl website showing the public transport option. The link has died as the date at which I planned the journey (and posted the answer) has passed, but the website offers you to plan the same route [today](http://9292.nl/en/journeyadvice/rotterdam_bus-tramhalte-metromaashaven/europoort-rotterdam_luxemburgweg/departure/2013-05-23T0456).

Comment: In my 2019 search the results are still in the same range of time. If you are not bound to Hull, traveling with a different ferry might be a better option. Both the Hook of Holland to Harwich and the IJmuiden/Amsterdam to Newcastle ferry are easier to reach with public transport on either end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can go to http://9292.nl/ for any itinerary with public transports in the Netherlands. One useful trick is to enter the postal code (3198 LG according to the [P&O website](http://www.poferries.eu/tourist/content/pages/template/routes_port-information_rotterdam-port_rotterdam-port.htm)) as point of departure or destination. In the Netherlands, a postal code corresponds to a specific street (and not a town or part of a town), so you can use it to find a route without having to worry about spelling the street name right or mixing up different streets of the same name.

In this particular case however, I couldn't find any good alternative. I don't have any personal experience with this particular route so I don't feel confident in recommending it but the only solution seems to be to go to the Pistoolhaven where you can get a ferry to Hoek van Holland (this is called the [“fast ferry”](http://www.ret.nl/en/travel-with-ret/timetable/fast-ferry.html) and is part of the Rotterdam transit system). There, you should be able to connect to the train and the rest of the country's public transport network. In this direction, it should take about 2 hours and cost a little over 17 € in total to reach Rotterdam Centraal (3.3€/person for the ferry and 5.3€/person for the train).

However, the way from the P&O terminal to Pistoolhaven looks quite long on the map. If you can find one, it could still make sense to catch a taxi (perhaps sharing it with some fellow travelers) just to go to the Pistoolhaven ferry terminal as it would presumably cost much less than going all the way to Rotterdam and basically divide your travel time in half. From there, the ferry + train connection looks quite good.

PS: I misread the question and described the way from the P&O terminal to Rotterdam but the same logic also applies in the other direction. Unfortunately, the ferry connections are even worse and I doubt you can rely on finding a taxi at Pistoolhaven. One might perhaps be arranged in advance with a local company. A quick google search [located this one](http://www.taxinijholt.nl/), you could call them to see what's possible and if the price is acceptable to you.

Also, walking might not be totally out of the question but seems *very* difficult, especially if you are carrying some luggage. The ferry terminal is in the middle of an industrial/port area and you would need to take a bridge to cross some river arm, total distance is 8 km. According to the 9292 website this works out to a total of 3 hours from Rotterdam Centraal (train + two different ferries + 1 hour waiting time between the ferries + more than 1 hour walk at the end). The connection between the train and the first ferry is extremely tight so be careful if you are considering taking the last ferry of the day.

Comment: I did a 2019 check on the OV9292 site and through Google maps.  Google maps could not find a public transport connection, the public transport site gave results very close to the ones in this answer. 89 minutes walking at the ferry end of the connection.