# Taxi from Pistoolhaven to Luxemburgweg Europoort in the Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, taxis, rotterdam

I got [excellent advice about travelling to Europoort](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17580/other-public-transport-from-rotterdam-central-station-to-europort) by other public transport with a dog. Could anybody advice me if and where I can book taxi from Pistoolhaven to Luxemburgweg P&O terminal in Netherlands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether there are any taxi companies dedicated to operating in the Europoort area, but based on the location of the Pistoolhaven, the closest town is Brielle. It appears that there are three taxi companies there. Source: http://www.telefoonboek.nl/zoeken/taxi/brielle/

The website includes phone numbers (telefoonnummer)

I have no experience with these companies, so I don't know what the quality of their service is.

Comment: Is Brielle closer to Pistoolhaven than Oostvoorne?

Comment: No, but Oostvoorne is even smaller, so I didn't expect any taxi companies there. You could easily check: http://www.telefoonboek.nl/zoeken/taxi/oostvoorne/ And there seem to be two there.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked it and a local taxi company can take us from Pistoolhaven to Europort Luxemburweg.:-)